# Iframe overlapping div issue

Tags: css, iframe

Using IE8, on this page: http://www.profilecoverpics.com/7/ , the Facebook comments iframe overlaps the footer div.

Screenshot: http://i.minus.com/iRPLwJweepBYQ.jpg

Is there a way to prevent the overlapping issue?

Answer (score 0):

Weird it works in Ie7 and not 8... try putting:
overflow:auto; on the dg-content-container id. That cleared it up for me in the IE8 dev tool bar. Looks like it wasn't containing a float.